# No sound in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, xubuntu, chromebook

I have dual-booted my Chromebook with Xubuntu 14.04 and have found that the sound is broken. I have tried everyhting that has been mentioned on the internet. I have restarted pulse, uninstalled it, unmuted sound in alsamixer, fiddled around with pavucontrol, and nothing. If this helps, there is no sound notifier in my taskbar, and I can't find a way to add one. Is it just it's unmuted in the hardware but the OS is just muted and I can't find a way to unmute it? BTW I have a Samsung Series 3 chromebook.

UPDATE 1: I have gotten sound notifier in my taskbar now, and it's on full volume, but nothing comes out.

UPDATE 2: I have tried installing drivers but they fail to install.

UPDATE 3: In the volume control, when I play Youtube videos, it shows audio playing in volume control but no sound is coming out. No, my speakers are not fried as they work fine in ChromeOS.

UPDATE 4: I uninstalled Pulse, and works on bootup, but the sound is blasting. When I lower the volume, it mutes. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the soundcard driver containing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then reboot.

Comment: I have done what you said, but sound still does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem (Xubuntu 14.04).  After updating, sound sometimes stops working, even though both input and output show graphically as working in Pulse controls.

Sometimes it has been restored by changing selections in the Configuration tab, but sometimes not.  This is extremely frustrating, as it seems to be random both as to when updates do this, and when manually selecting configuration in Pulse control fixes it.

Comment: This is kind of all over the place - it's not clear as to what it's really meant to solve.